# RapidJson and Data from Yahoo Weather

Tags: c++, json, qnetworkaccessmanager, rapidjson

I'm new to RapidJson, and I need to build an app using it.

For now what I have is a JSon string that I get from the Yahoo API Weather, it looks like this :

```
{
  query: {
        count: 1,
        created: "2015-10-21T20:40:02Z",
        lang: "fr-FR",
        results: {
              channel: {
                    item: {
                          condition: {
                                code: "27",
                                date: "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 9:59 pm CEST",
                                temp: "59",
                                text: "Mostly Cloudy"
                          }
                    }
              }
        }
  }
}
```

And my function that habdle the data is here :

```
void MyCurl::dataHandle(const std::string &data)
{
  //  std::cout << data << std::endl;                                                 

  Document d;
  d.Parse(data.c_str());

  std::cout << d["temp"].GetString() << std::endl;
}
```

The last line throw  :

`rapidjson/document.h :866 : rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>&` `rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](const` `rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator =` `rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator =` `rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]:  assertion <false> failed.`

How can I access to the temperature and the text ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the JSon is a bit special and I only had to dig throw all the array.

So now my line looks like :

```
std::cout << d["query"]["results"]["channel"]["item"]["condition"]["text"].GetString() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

The above string is not in a valid json format. You need to escape it. Instead of `{ temp : 23 }` it has to be `string json ="{/"temp/" : 23}";`

Also, you can perform error handling in RapidJson with `HasParseError()` and `IsString()`.